# Passing 2 Arguments to Maven Exec Plugin - Only Recognizes as 1 Argument

Tags: java, maven, arguments

I have a program that is ran from the command line with Maven. The program takes two arguments, 1) the name of the properties file used and 2) the name of the test to be ran.

Here is my exec plugin in my POM:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
<configuration>
     <mainClass>com.sensus.test.chefdeploytest.TestRunner</mainClass>
</configuration>
<executions>
   <execution>
     <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
     </goals>
     <phase>package</phase>
   </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

My main method:

```
public class TestRunner {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestRunner.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        if (args.length != 1){
            logger.error("Need the location of the properties file");
            System.exit(0);
        }

       ExternalProperties.setLocation(args[0]);
       String testName = args[1];
        JUnitCore core;
        Result result = null;

       if (testName.equals("Layer0")) {
            core = new JUnitCore();
            result = core.run(Layer0TestRunner.class);
        }
```

Here is what I put in the command line:

```
mvn package -Dexec.args="test.properties Layer0"
```

The Problem:
When I do this, the second argument of `Layer0` is not recognized as a second argument. Instead, `test.properties Layer0` is seen as one argument. Am I missing something to get this seen as two arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Boy don't I feel stupid, I overlooked this:

```
if (args.length != 1)
```

No wonder it wasn't recognizing them.